# Conditions for Hessian-vector products to be Lipschitz

Tags: functions, inequality, optimization, lipschitz-functions

I have a function $f$ that is $L_1$-smooth, and that has $L_2$-Lipschitz continuous
Hessian. Let the function $g$ be defined such that $g(x) = \nabla^2 f(x) x$. Under which conditions/assumptions, the function $g$ is Lipschitz continuous?

I tried the following:
\begin{align}
&\|g(x)-g(y)\|\\
&= \| \nabla^2 f(x) x- \nabla^2 f(y) y\|\\
&\leq \|\nabla^2 f(x)\| \|x-y\| + L_2\|x-y\|\|y\|
\end{align}

I guess I can make the assumption that $\|\nabla^2 f(x)\| \leq M$ where $M$ is a constant but I'm having an issue bounding the second term.